# How do I make a notepad document using the values from a database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I need some help with a java program. I am currently writing a code for a simple inventory system using NetBeans 7.3.

I want to know how to create a notepad document using values already stored in the database.

For example: I have a database called stock in which all product details are kept. When a supplier refills the stock, the stock table gets updated and the details of the transaction between shop owner and supplier gets saved in a table called GRN. So in the GRN I have the following columns: Supplier ID , Product ID , Quantity Bought , Total Value.

I want to know how to upload the data in the database into a simple notepad or text file or excel file... ANY FILE... once a button is pressed.

I am still a beginner to java so please do not use highly technical jargon :)

ALso, I am using My SQL Query Browser...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to read database info. As begginer, I recommend you to use JDBC (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

Then, you must create a simple text file, and write content you read from database to that file (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Good luck,